# Why are we trying to keep trees balanced

Tags: algorithm, tree

I see many questions that are talking about balanced tree.

For instance R-Tree are better than KD-Tree as they are balanced.

What is the advantage of using a balanced tree over a non-balanced tree?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Searching this tree

```
O
 \
  O
   \
    O
     \
      O
       \
        O
         \
          O
           \
            O
```

Is going to take Θ(N) time. Searching this tree

```
     O
   /   \
  O     O
 / \   / \
O   O O   O
```

Is going to take Θ(logN) time. Since search time is proportional to the height of the tree.

Comment: ...because the first tree has become a linked list.

Comment: what if the tree is ordered like a binary tree? would it matter?

Comment: I assume you mean a binary search tree, so the left child is smaller than the parent and the right child is bigger than or equal to the parent? That's possible in both cases. The first one is then a sorted list.

Comment: My question is if in that case - of the binary search tree it matters if the tree is balanced or not

Comment: @Odelya The first tree is unbalanced, the second one is balanced.

Comment: As shown in my answer, it matters a great deal. Searching a binary tree is done by checking if the root node is less than or greater than what you're searching for, and then recursively doing the same with the subtree to either the right or the left, respectively. When you get to the bottom of the tree you're done, so the worst-case running time of a search is proportional to the height of the tree. A balanced tree will have height proportional to log(n), whereas an unbalanced tree can potentially have a height proportional to n.

Answer (score 2):

It ensures minimum span for the average search.

If your tree isn't balanced, some searches will take longer than others. In the worst case, O(n).

Comment: Can you please explain more?

Comment: @Odelya - What don't you understand?

Comment: “It ensures minimum span for the average search.” What does that mean? What is “minimum span”? What is “average search”? Do you mean “average-case time complexity for search”?

Comment: @svick - I mean the "height" of the tree, but yes, “average-case time complexity for search” covers that too.